# How do we interpret general rules using Java?

Tags: java, rules, text-parsing

Say I have a very basic rule like the one below

```
if a<b
  then set a=25
else set a=-25
```

I need to evaluate this using my Java. What is the best approach to do these kind of parsing? Using regular expression could be very difficult and will be very difficult to maintain right?

Can someone please suggest an approach? Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Are you trying to create a syntax checker for your language or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see a Java implementation of Lexical Parser - JavaCC. Does it compiles the rule to a Java representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your syntax is regular, you can use regular expressions. If it is not, you need to use more complicated tools such as Lexers and Parsers: i.e. [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) or [Yacc/Lex/Bison](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/).

If you don't know much about language design, I suggest you read a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886) on the subject before you dive in.

Comment: Thanks for you reply David.I is not going to be that complicated. So is regular expression the best way to do this?

Comment: @Apps, regular expressions are used to match certain text given a predefined pattern. If you want to interpret the language (evaluate it), then regex is not the way to go, whether or not the target language is regular or not.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how/how much you can tweak your rule syntax you may be able to use Groovy or JRuby; they're both quite good at implementing tightly-integrated DSLs. I'd give that approach serious consideration before implementing an external DSL, although Antlr makes it pretty easy.